# Clearing out most recent emoji / emoticons?

Tags: keyboard, gboard, emoticons

Whenever I use an emoji / emoticon from the Google keyboard on Android, it gets added to the recent / most-used list of emoji.

This is generally useful, but there are times when I use an emoji just one time, and I prefer not to have it stored in the "most used" list.

Is there any way to remove just one or a few emojis from the most used list? Or even clear out the entire list and start from scratch?

Comment: I'm unsure that you can do that from inside the regular settings, aside from wiping all of the keyboard data, which is quite annoying. Speaking of a CyanogenMod keyboard, I was successful in clearing out the recently used emojis by editing the **com.android.inputmethod.latin_preferences.xml**, stored into the **/data/data/com.android.inputmethod.latin/shared_prefs/** directory. This requires root privileges, though.

Comment: Thanks! I found out how to reset using wiping out all keyboard data. Posted the answer. Will wait to see if there is a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to Settings app > Apps > Google Keyboard
2. Click "Storage"
3. Click "Clear Data"

This will remove / reset all your most recently used emojis so you can start from scratch.

Comment: This didn't work for me on Pixel 4.

Comment: It worked but it also reset all my keyboard settings. Is there a way to do this without resetting my settings?

Comment: This didn't work on my MI POCO X3 Pro mobile

Answer (score 0):

And if you’d like certain ones there asap then text a friend or business (knowing it’ll be a landline) a couple times with all the emoji you’d like. Tap them a few times if necessary. It usually works in 2 texts for me. Text the grocery store. No one cares and it won’t go through anyway. I prefer this method over resets bc I don’t know what else I’m clearing that I may want